# docusign signature_image USER_DOES_NOT_EXIST_IN_SYSTEM

Tags: docusignapi

GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information

```
$postData = json_encode(array(
  'emailSubject'=>'THIS SHOULD NEVER BE SEEN',
  'status'=>'created',
  'templateId'=>'AEC7B6E9-F978-2C48-B418-2B75931207FD',
  'templateRoles'=>array(
  )
));
```

too
POST baseUrl/envelopes

GET baseUrl/envelopes/$envelopeId/recipients/1/tabs

modify the tab info

PUT baseUrl/envelopes/$envelopeId/recipients/1/tabs

Everything works up to this point... then I do the actual signing.

```
$postData=image.png (<60 KB)
$headers['contentType'] = 'Content-Type: image/png';
$headers['contentLength'] = 'Content-Length:'.strlen($postData);
```

too

PUT baseUrl/envelopes/envelopeId/recipients/1/signature_image

fails with

```
{
  "errorCode": "USER_DOES_NOT_EXIST_IN_SYSTEM",
  "message": "The UserID did not identify a User in the system."
}
```

I can't find any info on what I am supposed to do to get this to work...

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish. Can you update your question to include a description of your scenario and what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: sign the document from a custom signing interface... essentially acting as a proxy to docusign.

Comment: I now know that adding an email address will get rid of the error message, however after signing the document it will still be considered an unsent draft,  if I change the envelope status to sent and have a bogus email address, it will merely be listed as "out for signature" when I have already signed it automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, technically speaking, the scenario you're trying to accomplish -- i.e., automatically applying signature(s) to document(s) by using the API -- is possible by using the ***Offline Signing*** feature of the DocuSign API.  However, as the name implies, "offline signing" is intended to facilitate scenarios where the Signer is not connected to the internet when signing -- not to facilitate an application's ability to automatically apply signatures for signers (bypassing DocuSign's interface altogether, even though the Signer is connected to the Internet).

***Offline Signing*** is described on pages 130-131 of the DocuSign REST API guide (https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/rest-api-guide-v2.pdf).  As stated in the guide, Offline Signing is not available to you by default -- that capability must be specifically granted to your Integrator Key by DocuSign.  So, I'd suggest you contact DocuSign to explain your scenario and ask that they enable ***Offline Signing*** for your Integrator Key.

If/when DocuSign enables ***Offline Signing*** for your Integrator Key, you should be able to create/send the Envelope (automatically applying signature tabs for any signer having **routingOrder = 1**) in one API call -- see **"Offline Signing Settings and Restrictions"** on p131 of the guide I've linked to above for information on how this is done.

Regardless of whether or not DocuSign is willing to enable ***Offline Signing*** for your Integrator Key, I'd suggest you consider embedding the DocuSign signing interface within your application (as an alternative to building your own signing interface). This is a fairly easy/straight-forward process; the DocuSign Developer Center contains some good info about how this is done: https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign.

Comment: Thanks, we got in contact with them, they did not allow us to use offline signing for our purpose.  We are now using embedded signing.